# Error when trying to build Rmarkdown site

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to build a `rmarkdown` site for a final class project. I am getting an odd error in the build window. I reinstalled `stringi` and made sure it was installed/loaded. Any ideas on how to get a round this? I am currently using `version 1.24` of `stringi` in `MacOS`.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

**Code & Error:**

```
==> rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

> Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) :    shared object
>   'stringi.so' not found Calls:  ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList
>   -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

--Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the package and then reinstall it with the following contingencies.

install.packages("stringi",type="mac.binary")